# React ternary operator with array data not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Update: Solution below

I'm trying to make these icons from my data file appear, but it's showing [object object] and then undefined for the data that doesn't have any icons

Here is what I wrote that shows the errors

```
    <div>
      {dropdown ? `${item.iconClosed}` : `${item.iconOpened}`}
    </div>
```

Basically I want the icons to only show if dropdown menu is opened or closed.

If I just do

```
    <div>{item.iconClosed}</div>
```

it shows up completely fine. But when I try to add an if or else statement I can't seem to figure out the proper way to write it

Note in the data file, it's just an icon as the value

```
   iconClosed: <RiIcons.RiArrowDownSFill />,
   iconOpened: <RiIcons.RiArrowUpSFill />,
```

Also, I have data that does not have any icons, so how would I write the logic to only show these icons if the value exist or not?

My logic was this

```
if(dropdown) {
show upArrow
} else if(dropdown === false) {
show downArrow
} else {
 show null
 }
```

My issue is how would I write this as a ternary operator inside of my div?

```
<div>{dropdown && dataContainsDropdown ? "downArrow" : " "}</div>
```

The problem here is that I can't check if the dropdown is open and to show the upArrow

Updated answer that worked

```
   <div>
      {item.dropDown && dropdown
        ? item.iconOpened
        : item.dropDown
        ? item.iconClosed
        : null}
    </div>
```

Comment: how `dropdown` changes its state?

Comment: if I do `{item.dropDown ? 'upArrow' : ' '}` then it will show the arrow icon for data that only contains dropdown data. But the dropdown gets triggered when I click on the main menu item

Comment: What are the possible values of `dropdown`? Your question does not make that clear.

Comment: I found a solution and added the updated code below, but I had to manually add the icons. I still don't know the proper way to pass the icon values from my data file instead of hard coding them above

Answer (score 4):

```
dropdown ? `${item.iconClosed}` : `${item.iconOpened}`
```

The problem here is that you put your icon into a template string, so the result will be a string (later added to the DOM). Since your icon is an object, it will be stringified using the default Object toString method which returns "[Object object]"

You don't need template string at all here so just do:

```
dropdown ? item.iconClosed : item.iconOpened
```

edit: you can combine more than one condition with logical AND/OR before the `?` if you want to make sure your item has icons

Answer (score 2):

You're getting `[object Object]` because you're trying to render an object as a string.

```
    <div>
      {/* if item.iconClosed is a React element, don't put it in a string */}
      {dropdown ? `${item.iconClosed}` : `${item.iconOpened}`}
      {/* just use it directly as the evaluated result of your ternary */}
      {dropdown ? item.iconClosed : item.iconOpened}
    </div>
```

Now if you want handle the case where there's no icon, either for closed or open, you could do this.

```
function MyComponent() {
  // ...other component code
  let icon = dropdown ? item.iconClosed : item.iconOpened
  icon = !icon ? null : icon
  
  return (
    // ...other jsx returned from element
    <div>{icon}</div>
  )
}
```

Now, there are some other things here that are not very idiomatic for React, but I won't go into those unless you'd like me to.

Comment: +1 for the tests out of the render. Also if OP is sure that an undefined icon is either `undefined` or `null` the fallback check is unnecessary since React won't render these values.

Comment: Yes, but since you cannot return `undefined` from a component, I find it's better to stick to a single empty value, `null`, when working in React. This way, if you refactor, and something that was previously a value within some other JSX becomes the return of a component, it won't break.

Comment: You cannot return `undefined` from a component, but using `undefined` within JSX is no problem. `<p>{undefined}</p>` renders an empty `<p>` element. If you really want to stick to `null` you could replace `icon = !icon ? null : icon` with `icon ||= null` assuming your Babel is up to date. See: [Logical OR assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that from each JSX template the compiler creates an object with all the information React needs to create that node [1]. So when you use any of them in a template string it calls `.toString` which returns `[object Object]`. For solving your problem just get rid of template strings:

```
    <div>
      {dropdown ? `${item.iconClosed}` : `${item.iconOpened}`}
    </div>
```

[1] the reality is that the compiler just calls a function provided by React which creates the object needed.